# php only calculate sales tax for state residents only

Tags: php

Is there an easy way to do this say i have their zipcode and i only want to charge state residents and none state residents dont get charged

Comment: Do you have a database with the zip code info? If so, it should be pretty simple to check which state they're in an use a conditional statement to charge or not charge the sales tax.

Comment: I don't even see why you need to use the zip.  It seems like a lot of complexity for just if($state == 'CA'){$taxable = true;} else {$taxable = false;} And if you only have their zipcode would it not be easier to just ask for state?

Comment: @Jason Benson: Even worse is that zip codes may not be able to return the correct state (check out my answer below).

Answer (score 3):

**US ZIP codes can cross state lines** so they are not wholly reliable in determining sales tax burdens. You must use the customer's state information or a combination of state and ZIP.

Answer (score 1):

I would find a "zip code" data source and make a list of all zip codes in the desired state. Then just do a simple match and if you find a matching zip, add sales tax.

Answer (score 1):

The USPS would be the canonical reference for zip codes and states.  It happens that [they also provide an API](http://www.usps.com/webtools/welcome.htm) to look up this sort of thing (look under "Address Information APIs").  With this live data, you don't have to worry about whether a downloaded database is up-to-date.

Comment: For many people, depending on a 3rd party API (especially one from an organization run as poorly as USPS) is out of the question. Zip Codes RARELY change, and I have been using on-site data for years and years with no problems.